# Need some ASP.NET MVC Routing Help

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've started with ASP.NET MVC recently, reading blogs, tutorials, trying some routes, etc. Now, i've stumbled on a issue where i need some help.

Basically, i have an URL like /products.aspx?categoryid=foo&productid=bar

Most tutorials/examples propose to map this to something like: /products/category/foo/bar where "products" is the controller, "category" is the action, etc.

But i need to map it to /products/foo/bar. (without "category")

Is it possible? Am i missing something? Help will be highly appreciated. Thank you advance :)

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(your English is just fine, no need to apologize!)*

You can define a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("productsByCategory", "products/{category}/{productid}",
  new { controller="products", action="findByCategory" })
```

This will match

`products/foo/bar`  and call an action looking like this:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
   ...

   public ActionResult FindByCategory(string category, string productid)
   {
          ....
   }
}
```

does this help?

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm starting like the framework more and more L:)

Answer (score 0):

You also might consider making a Controller to test out your custom routes...

Check out [Stephen Walther's blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/08/03/asp-net-mvc-tip-29-build-a-controller-to-debug-your-custom-routes.aspx) about it.

Comment: You should write unit tests to test your custom routes.  It's automated and we need to run it every time we make a change to controllers, actions, or routes, so why rely on a manual check?